# VB.NET not creating database in sql server 2008 express

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013

I am developing a vb.net winform project to take in details of visitors into a business. I am using a sql server 2008 express database to store the details.
 When the application starts, it checks for a database, if it's there it continues on but if it's not it creates the database in sql server 2008 express.
The code attached is supposed to create the database if it doesn't exist (well, it's supposed to anyway). The program will go through the code that's supposed to create the database no problem but will throw an error in the form load at sqlCon.Open, the error is: 'Cannot open database "Visitors" requested by the login. The login failed.' It would be greatly appreciated if someone could tell me where I am going wrong?

```
Private Sub allVisitors_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.Text = "All Visitors"

    If Not checkDatabaseExists() Then

        Dim Result1 = MessageBox.Show("Database does not exist, press OK to continue and create database. Press Cancel to close.", "Create database", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
        If Result1 = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            createVisitorsDatabase() 'Calls sub to create database
            createTablesForVisitors() 'Calls sub to create tables in database
        ElseIf Result1 = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
            Me.Close()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        MessageBox.Show("Database has been created. Press OK to continue.", "Database created", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    Else

        Dim Result2 = MessageBox.Show("Datebase exists, press OK to continue. Press Cancel to close.", "Dateabase exists", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
        If Result2 = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        ElseIf Result2 = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
            Me.Close()
            Exit Sub
        End If

    End If

    connectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Visitors;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"

    sql = "SELECT idNumber, firstName, lastName, company FROM visitorDetails"

    sqlCon = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

    sqlCon.Open() 'Error thrown here.
    'Error is : Cannot open database "Visitors" requested by the login. The login failed.

    sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon)

    da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlCon)

    dt = loadDtVisitorDetails()
    fillDgvVisitorDetails(dt)

    sqlCmd.Dispose()
    sqlCon.Close()

End Sub

Public Sub createVisitorsDatabase()

    connectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"

    sql = "CREATE DATABASE Visitors"

    sqlCon = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

    sqlCon.Open()
    sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon)

    da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlCon)

    sqlCmd.Dispose()
    sqlCon.Close()

End Sub

Public Sub createTablesForVisitors()

    connectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"

    sql = " USE Visitors " & _
   "CREATE TABLE visitorDetails " & _
   "(idNumber int NOT NULL, firstName varchar(25) NOT NULL, lastName varchar(40) NOT NULL, company varchar(150) NOT NULL, " & _
   "contactNumber varchar(50) NOT NULL, countryCode varchar(1000) NOT NULL, photoId varchar(1000) NULL, email varchar(150) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (idNumber)) " & _
   "CREATE TABLE reasonForVisit " & _
   "(idNumber int, dateOnSite varchar(20), reasonForVisit varchar(150))"

    sqlCon.Open()
    sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon)

    da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlCon)

    sqlCmd.Dispose()
    sqlCon.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello - check the default database for your login and make sure that it isn't set (or blank) to a database you don't have access to or doesn't exist. If it doesn't exist, it'll be blank, change it to something like master and re-test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace the line

```
da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlCon)
```

with

```
sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

to execute your CREATE DATABASE.